# How to cudaMemcpy host values pointed by an array of pointers to a device array Cuda

Tags: c, memory-management, cuda

I am trying to find a way, if it is possible, to copy the values that are pointed by a host array of pointers `pts` that points to some elements of another host array `s` (`float2` type). The values that need to be dereferenced from `pts` with the `->` operator are in random positions in the `s` array.

Is there a way to copy these values pointed by `pts` without having to use an intermediate host buffer to write the values in it before using `cudaMemcpy`? 
I only came up with a for loop copying one element at a time but isnt this redundant?
I use cuda 5.5
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values you want to copy are in random locations, and you want to copy only those values to the device, you will need to write a separate loop in host code that aggregates those values first into a single contiguous buffer.

You can then copy that buffer using an ordinary approach like `cudaMemcpy`.